# What are the different names of anti-collusion laws?

Tags: legal-terms, definition

Anti-collusion laws have different names. For example, they are called "antitrust laws" and "anti-monopoly laws" in China following [Nishan (2021)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3845997), and "anti-collusion laws" in India following [Dasgupta (2019)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/32/7/2587/5079300?redirectedFrom=fulltext).

What other names have been used for these laws?

Comment: I think law stack exchange is much better equipped to handle this question.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that "antitrust laws" and "anti-monopoly laws" and "anti-collusion laws" are all used.

Probably the most common name that you have haven't mentioned is "unfair competition" laws.